# Count distinct items not previously counted

Tags: sql, count, conditional-statements

I would like to do a count of distinct items that have been counted in a previous month and should not be counted in the current month ..  if itemid2 was counted in September then itemid2 should not be counted in October
Thanks for ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: You can group by an item then use a nested sub query and use `NOT IN`.

Comment: What mean `not been counted in a previous month` ? Hello welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
  [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
   much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add a column 'countedIn' to the table and record the month there when counted. Then `select count(distinct itemid) from table where countedIn is null` and `update table set countedIn = 'November' where countedIn is null`